# angular2 and formControlName value in template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Oh angular2...why so hard?

```
<input type="text" formControlName="exposure" type="hidden">
<label>{{exposure}}</label>
```

If I use the formControlName in the input the value is correct.

How do I get the value of exposure in template?  Its blank in the label

Answer (score 55):

> The `formControlName` directive is designed to be used with a parent
>   `FormGroupDirective` (selector: `[formGroup]`).
>
> It accepts the string name of the `FormControl` instance you want to
>   link, and will look for a `FormControl` registered with that name in
>   the closest `FormGroup` or `FormArray` above it.

Use `form.get('exposure').value` to get the control value.

Example:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="text" formControlName="exposure" type="hidden">
    <label>{{ form.get('exposure').value }}</label>
</form>
```

### Alternatively

In your component class, define a getter property representing your form control:

```
export class MyComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({
    exposure: new FormControl('')
  });

  get exposure(): FormControl { return this.form.get('exposure'); }
```

Then, in your component template, you can reference `exposure`:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="exposure" type="hidden">
<label>{{exposure.value}}</label>
```

Comment: is there really no alternative to this? feels kinda cumbersome. Would be nice to bind a template variable to the underlying control on the input element

Comment: And this snippet from the doc, show another way, but not working for me...

`<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div *ngIf="first.invalid"> Name is too short. </div>
 
      <input formControlName="first" placeholder="First name">
      <input formControlName="last" placeholder="Last name">
 
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
   <button (click)="setValue()">Set preset value</button>`
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#model

Comment: `<div class="col-lg-6" *ngFor="let keyArray of keyArray"><mat-form-field><input type="text" [formControlName]="keyArray.key" matInput [placeholder]="keyArray.name|titlecase" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':submitted && f.keyArray.key.errors}" /><mat-error *ngIf="submitted && f.keyArray.key.hasError('required')">
{{keyArray.name}}is required</mat-error><mat-error *ngIf="submitted && keyArray.key=='phone' && f.keyArray.key.hasError('minlength')">{{keyArray.name}}must be 10 digits</mat-error></mat-error></mat-form-field></div>` I am done with dynamic formGroup,Validators.How should I do this with HTML?

Answer (score 19):

Declare a template variable:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="exposure" type="hidden" #exposure>
<label>{{ exposure.value }}</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to print the current field values of a form in your template for testing purpose.

Use

```
<p>{{myForm.value|json}}</p>
```

[image]

Comment: This way you are showing data from the component in the template, not the value from the form control.