# formControlName input value undefined

Tags: html, angular, forms, typescript

I have a problem with formControlName, I want to submit this form, but one input is undefined, like in photo.

[image]

in console look my submit:

[image]

I used this code:

```
<form [formGroup]="addProductForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddProduct()" class="col s12" materialize style="text-align:center">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input formControlName="Quantity" id="Quantity " type="number" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="Quantity">
             </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input formControlName="Unit_price" id="Unit_price" type="number" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="Unit_price">
           </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
     <div class="c1" style="text-align:left;">
        Subtotal:
      <input formControlName="Subtotal" id="Subtotal" type="number" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="Subtotal" [value]="Quantity*Unit_price">
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div id="add_contrat_button_container" class="row">
    <button id="add_contrat_button" type="submit" class="button button1">
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Please, can you look and ask me what is the problem in this code, In `Subtotal` set automatic this value `[value]="Quantity*Unit_price"` but don't submit. Thank you

Comment: You use `formControlName` and `ngModel`. Remove one and try again. And in both cases, you don't need to use `[value]`

Comment: plus 1 for trichetriche's comment. BTW, `[value]` supports string only, `[ngValue]` supports any type

Comment: @trichetriche I use togather because, this value I can change and the subtotal will be change. Also, I try and nothing change

Comment: If you want to make a subtotal then you should listen on the `(input)` event, not use both form modules.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to remove your ngModel since you already use formControlName. The you check at this link [angular2 and formControlName value in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732375/angular2-and-formcontrolname-value-in-template). It may be helpful to you. And I don't understand why you need to do so. I think you should set the value for Subtotal after you submit the form is a better solution. And change the input for subtotal to a normal text field to display it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, If I not used [(ngModel)] I don't display Unit_price and Quantity  in [value]="Quantity*Unit_price"

Comment: Can you write please some code, how to solution this?