# How do i display the value of a form control in the html view?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I know this sounds super simple but I can't get it to work. I know that I have to use the mustache tags to display it, but it just isn't displayed when I type something in the form field. Here is my code:

```html
<label>Variety name: {{seedForm.get('varietyName').value}}</label>
```

Here is the actual formfield:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Variety name</mat-label>
    <input matInput name="variety" type="text" placeholder="The name of the variety" autofocus
        formControlname="varietyName" required>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is the seedform definition:

```
this.seedForm = fb.group({
  'varietyName' : ['', Validators.required]
})
```

I don't understand why this code doesn't display the value I type in. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Try seedForm.controls.varietyName.value. Don't forget to check if seedForm is not undefined.

Comment: doesn't work either

Comment: And if you create a FormControl when initializing the FormGroup? varietyName: new FormControl({ value: null }, [Validators.required])

Comment: i checked if seedForm is undefined by adding this     console.log(this.seedForm === undefined); to the submit method. It returns false

Comment: Did you try to create the FormControl like I said?

Comment: I am working with a formbuilder that excepts only abstract controls. I made a seperate abstract control like so: this.varietyName = this.seedForm.get('varietyName'); But when i use this in the mustache tags it doesn't display anything either

Comment: i don't understand because i'm doing it the exact same wayas this guy does here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732375/angular2-and-formcontrolname-value-in-template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174421/discussion-between-powkachu-and-maurice).

Comment: when i display the contents of seedForm itself like so: {{seedForm.value | json}} I see all the empty fields displayed as text, however this json printout is'nt being updated when i type something in one of the fields

Comment: Do you have a <form> tag?

Comment: of course haha, i tried the same with seedForm.status like so: {{ seedForm.status | json }} but it doesn't update from INVALID to VALID either, when i type something in.

Comment: So weird! Can you show more code? Like your HTML form and where you're initialising your FormBuilder?

Comment: I am going to do this because things have become even stranger! There is one other field in the html view whose named 'color' and whose value IS being updated in the view. I will update my question with the full code, one moment.

Comment: I think color is working because it is the last and overwrite others.

Comment: thats not it, I changed it so that varietyName is now last. Yet the only field whose value is displayed it that of color

Comment: Try to create a plunker or something like that, then we might be more useful.

Comment: If you remove 'color', are other fields working?

Comment: nope, and when i remove all the fields except for variety name its STILL not working this is ridiculous!

Comment: the reason why only color works is: because color is the only field that has formControlName correctly spelled :(. All the others miss the capital letter N. aAAaaAaAAaAAaaAaArrggghhhhh!!! and why doesn't the browser or angular throw any errors?! Ooh man.. Well, mystery solved i guess. Only took me about an hour or so to solve :S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can display the value in the HTML template/view via Angular's string interpolation as follows:

```
<div>
    <h5> Seed Variety </h5>

    {{seedForm.controls.varietyName.value}}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you have to write formGroup on parent tag and also Init your form check this **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohfns7)**